# Direct printing in oracle apex

Tags: oracle-apex, xsl-fo, oracle-apex-5

I use xsl-fo printing in my application developed in oracle apex. I want to send the report directly to the printer without showing it on the screen. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: No you can't. Apex is a Web-Application running in a Browser. A browser can't force-print stuff.

**Long answer** (Just a crazy solution for a crazy problem): You could create a webserver which is running on the Computer where the Report is downloaded.
If you are in Oracle Apex just make an Ajax Request to that webserver and pass the XSL-FO as the Body. That webserver can then send that data in the right format to the printer. As a Webserver you could maybe try a C++ application, it requires a lot of integration and fiddling with printer drivers though. It turns out C++/C# applications are a lot more assertive than browsers.

Comment: I have heard about web server printing, and character printing from web browser using  java client . If you know about character printing using java client, please update the answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: That's a different question. If you want to do it with Apex you can't, if you want to do it with a Java Client that is integrated into Apex that has nothing (or at least very little) to do with Apex anymore.